# docker-compose not setting environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up redis`, with `environment` specified in `docker-compose.yaml` and `RUN env` in the `Dockerfile`, the environment variables I set don't get printed.

Why does this not work?

I'm using `docker-compose` version 1.4.2.

Here are the relevant files:

**`docker-compose.yaml` with `environment` as a list of `KEY=value` pairs:**

```
redis:
    build: ../storage/redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    environment:
      - FOO='bar'
```

**`docker-compose.yaml` with `environment` as a dictionary:**

```
redis:
    build: ../storage/redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    environment:
      - FOO: 'bar'
```

**`Dockerfile`:**

```
FROM redis:2.6
MAINTAINER me@email.com

RUN mkdir -p /var/redis && chown -R redis:redis /var/redis

RUN echo '-------------- env ---------------'
RUN env

COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
EXPOSE 6379
ENTRYPOINT ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
```

Answer (score 23):

That's normal

`docker-compose` only sets the environment variables specified in the `environment` directive in the `docker-compose.yaml` file during the run phase of the container, and not during the build phase.

So if you do `docker-compose run --entrypoint "/bin/bash" redis -c env` you will be able to see your env variables.

If you want to set variables inside your Dockerfile (to be able to see them during the build phase) you can add inside your dockerfile before your `RUN env`:

```
ENV FOO bar
```

Comment: When I run `$ docker-compose run redis env`, I get: `*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 493
>>> '"env"'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments1`

Comment: Ah ok sorry I did not see you changed the entrypoint. In your case do `docker-compose run redis /bin/bash -c env` @Neil

Comment: Running that emits: `Bad directive or wrong number of arguments`

Comment: Are you saying that `docker-compose` sets those environment variables in my own shell that runs `docker compose up redis`? How do you get the `docker-compose` environment to persist into the container? What is the point of the `environment` directive if this isn't done automatically?

Comment: You mentioned "during the build phase", where can I get the container to print the environment after the build phase is complete? I just want my running container to have access to the environment set in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: `docker-compose` sets those env variables in the containers your start using `docker-compose` commands. So they persist and are available. I am just showing you how to view them here.

Comment: And when the build phase is complete, you have an image not a container so there is nothing to show, nothing is running. To interact with your image you have to start a container based on this image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92166/discussion-between-aurelien-bottazini-and-neil).

Comment: @Neil edit the command to see all your env variables with another entrypoint. `docker-compose run --entrypoint "/bin/bash" redis -c env`

Comment: There is an upcoming release that will support this. See [github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2111) for details

Answer (score 3):

Well
I have tested and found following solutions for docker compose with env file or without env file. I will show you two different approach

Lets say you have following docker compose yml file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
db:
image: postgres:13
volumes:
 - "./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
ports:
 - "5432:5432"
env_file: docker.env
```

Now you need to setup the postgres variable in a file called docker.env. Remember you need to keep the docker_compose.yml file and docker.env file in same folder.
Next, In the docker.env file you need to have the database variable and value like this:

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=myapp_db
```

Now hit docker-compose up . It should work.
Lets say now you dont like to specify the env file name in the docker-compose.yml file. So you have to write docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
db:
  image: postgres:13
  volumes:
    - "./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environments:
     - POSTGRES_USER=${PGU}
     -POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PGP}
     -POSTGRES_DB=${PGD}
```

Now your docker.env file should look like this:

```
PGU=postgres
PGP=postgres
PGD=myapp_db
```

now hit docker-compose --env-file docker.env up

you are good to go.

Comment: Using an env_file is a lot easier and provides greater seperation from the docker-compose file. Moreover, if you have heavily nested environments, i was ONLY able to get it to work using a seperate .env file instead of including it in the compose file.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you were using `environment` when (I guess) you wanted to use `args` inside the `build` block:

```
redis:
    build: 
      context: ../storage/redis
      args:
        - FOO: 'bar'
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
```

And `FUN` would be defined as follows (in your Dockerfile):

```
FROM redis:2.6

RUN mkdir -p /var/redis && chown -R redis:redis /var/redis

# Read FUN from (build) arguments 
# (may define a default: ARG FUN='wow')
ARG FUN

# Define env variable FUN with value from ARG
ENV FUN=$FUN

RUN echo '-------------- env ---------------'
RUN env

COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
EXPOSE 6379
ENTRYPOINT ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
```

> The `environment` block is used to define variables for the running container (when `docker-compose up`, *NOT* when `docker-compose build`).
>
> Similar answer to a similar question, may be of interest:
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74315994/687896

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: If you need to use environments, use an ENV file instead of placing it into a compose file.  When placing environment variables in a docker-compose file (list of environment variables) and those variables are referencing each other, the docker-loader does not correctly join those correctly.

**Explanation**:

**The long and short is, the Environment variables when placed in a .env file are evaluated BEFORE being provided to the running docker environment**. This allows for specific environment variables to be made dynamically (see in my example below of the connection string leveraging the environment variables in the ENV file).

Use this Instead

```
version: '3.8'
services:
db:
image: postgres:13
volumes:
 - "./volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
ports:
 - "5432:5432"
env_file: docker.env
```

docker.env file contains:

```
   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Test
    DATABASE_USER=lawguy007
    DATABASE_PASSWORD=myPasswordIsBoring
    DATABASE_SERVER=192.168.1.25    
    ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server="${DATABASE_SERVER}";Include Error Detail=true;Database=threatlists;User Id=${DATABASE_USER};Password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```