# Docker-compose environment variable is not set

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Project tree

```
/backend
  .env.dev
  docker-compose-dev.yml
  /project
```

I have the following warning:

```
docker-compose  -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build # i am in the /backend directory

WARNING: The DB_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DB_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DB_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

It means that docker compose don't see my environment file. How can I fix it?

docker-compose-dev.yml

```
services:
  django:
    build: ./project # path to Dockerfile
    command: sh -c " 
      sleep 3 && gunicorn -w 8 --bind 0.0.0.0:8800 core_app.wsgi"
    volumes:
      - ./project:/project
      - ./project/static:/project/static
      - ./project/media:/project/media
      - ./project/logs:/project/logs
    expose:
      - 8800
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose: 
      - 5432
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
          .......
```

How can I enable env file?

P.S
Values are set in the file `.env.dev`

```
DB_NAME=db_dev
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=passsss132132
ENV_TYPE=DEV
```

**UPDATE**
Found out that this way is working

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml  --env-file=.env.dev up
```

Comment: where is your db container in compose file?

Comment: [The solution is to use single quote instead of double quote in `.env` file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73575077/6141587)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the complaint is coming from *docker* (compose) itself, try to:

1. rename `./.env.dev` to simply `.env.dev`;
2. if not yet, rename `.env.dev` to `.env` (default) and remove the `env_file` entry from your compose. That will certainly work, then you can go back to investigate the issue with `env_file` ([1]).

#### Update

Now facing the same problem myself -- in a similar situation trying to separate the variables of [my JupyterHub](https://github.com/dockerstuff/jupyterhub-deploy-docker) from that destined to the Jupyter Notebooks --, I digged in a bit more to understand better the role of Compose's `.env` and `env_file:`.

As already informed in the question, the use of option `--env-file` solves the issue. Which is the right answer for defining *docker-compose's (yaml)* environment variables in a file named differently from `.env` (default).

The `env_file` option in `docker-compose.yaml` is meant for the container being run: only the container sees those variables.

> I recently posted a similar answer to a similar question :
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538969/687896

[1] https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Comment: I need two .env files (one for dev, one for prod)

Comment: Right. And that's good practice. My advice "2" is for testing purposes only. If you ever want to really understand what is going on.