# NextJS APP not read environment variables from docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, next.js

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
image: image
container_name: cc_fe
ports:
  - "4096:4096"
environment:
  - NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGO=/xyz.png
  - NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGODARK=/logo-dark.png
  - NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGODARK=true
  - NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=https://example.com/api
volumes:
  - ./frontend/public/:/app/public
```

Dockerfile for frontend. If any variable exist in Dockerfile, it is not showing.
For example, if i delete NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGO config from Dockerfile than build, project reads physical `.env` file, whenever i add config below, it never shows.

```
FROM node:16

RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get install -y yarn

WORKDIR /app

ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGO

ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGO=${NEXT_PUBLIC_LOGO}
   
# Copy .env file
COPY ./.env .

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Copy source files
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN yarn build

# Start the application
CMD if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then yarn start -p $(grep '^PORT=' .env | cut -d '=' -f2); else yarn start -p "$PORT"; fi
```

After all done, when i go to container shell,`process.env`  i can see my updated envoriment variables.

I'm not a frontend expert, but i don't know what is going on. Searched lots of sources for this problem, i tried almost all of them, but not able to manage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose not setting environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107164/docker-compose-not-setting-environment-variables)

Comment: @Vish not exactly. I want to define envoriments from my compose file only. Docker process.env config seems okay when i ``process.env`` on the frontend container.

But idk.

Comment: @Cagrison if you use compose you don't have to set anything in the Dockerfile, compose will handle it automatically. It works the same way as `docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE` etc. Is that what you wanted to know? If not, please clarify the question a bit :)

Comment: @Danila thanks for reply. Understood, i removed ENV from Dockerfile. I saw that command that you wrote before, but sometimes i had 30-40 envoriment in my project, do i have to add every variable to command ``docker run -e variable=val`` ?

Comment: Nonono, you don't have to add anything. Just keep your variables in the compose file and that's it. I meant that when running compose with env it's more or less equal to `docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE`. So you don't need anything in your Dockerfile, just put everything in the compose file.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I removed ENV from Dockerfile, kept it only in my docker-compose.yml.

Now, project only reads my pyhsical ``.env`` . Not getting ENV variables from compose. :/

Here is frontend container process.env result which is correct and same with yaml:  https://prnt.sc/IokmazdgI1Og

Here is project log after build: https://prnt.sc/kvbiVk5nHBp0

I think these values not read for production build ?

Comment: Hi @Cagrison, Have you solved the problem? I have the same one now.

Comment: @xyxc hi. Yes i've solved my problem. 
Set your ENV (for only next_public tags) then make an entrypoint.sh in your Dockerfile.

https://prnt.sc/GigSIDsPuixm

replacer.sh

https://prnt.sc/yS74Bwl6t8mo

I do not know this is a propery solution. But it works for me.